# Core difference between VMware Workstation and VirtualBox bridged networking?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I have both VMware workstation and VirtualBox on my development system at home. I'm working on an infrastructure mock up where I have multiple VMs that host Let's Encrypt TLS certificates and because of being at home, I'm using DDNS pointing to my public IP address that's routed to a proxy server, that will (eventually) redirect traffic to those VMs based upon the requesting hostname. The idea is that the VMs will be accessible to both online (test) systems, as well as local VMs on the same network, whether that be virtual or physical LAN.

To build the proxy server, I started using VirtualBox, spun up an Ubuntu VM with a bridged network to my physical LAN, installed nginx on it and obtained the certificates (manual mode, using DNS-01 challenges). I apply the certs and then use an external port checker to see if an outside entity can see my public IP on port 443, it fails.

I have documented exactly how I've built everything and tested a number of times: it never works on VirtualBox, but it always works on VMware: I build the **exact same** system on VMware, using a bridged NIC, and the outside entity sees the proxy server no problem.
[image]

It leads me to think that there is a native difference in bridged networking between VirtualBox and VMware (which is to be expected, I'm sure) but wondered if anyone has experienced this before and - furthermore - knows of a way to overcome this with VirtualBox?

**More Info:**

1. My ISP blocks port 80, but permits 443.
2. Ideally I'd like to use VirtualBox as my IDE connects to it using vagrant, making it quicker and easier to update server side files, etc.
3. In an ideal world all VMs would be able to connect to each other using a VirtualLAN so that I keep the traffic off of the physical LAN, with the sole exception of those VMs that external traffic needs to be routed to, in which case they'll have the bridged NIC (and probably a HostOnly NIC too).
4. UFW is installed on both VirtualBox/VMware hosts - disabling it makes no difference.
5. I've tried Promiscuous Mode: Allow All on VirtualBox too, to no avail.